# Multiple Criteria If Condition - Identify highest number based upon preceding criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a bit of a tracker within Excel/Google Sheets to identify which 'home loan' has the combination of highest interest rate PLUS loan/mortgage size.

The formula I've built so far works for the below conditions;

1. There is only 1 loan with the highest interest rate, or;
2. If there are multiple loans that have the highest interest rate, the loan that is the largest is included within that condition.

Where this formula doesn't work is when;

- When there are multiple loans with the highest interest rate, however these loans are NOT the largest loan size... I believe the issue is due to the fact I'm including a 'max' statement as part of the match condition. Please see cell reference I8:L10 as an example.

I'm unsure how to achieve this within a formula to identify;

1. The loan with the highest interest rate
2. Of the loans with the highest interest rate, which has the largest mortgage/loan size.

**Please note the Interest Rate's vary within the data set**

Formula Used:
=if(countif($E3:$H3,max($E3:$H3))>1,
if(iserror(index($E$1:$H$1,match(1,(max($E3:$H3)=E3)*(max($A3:$D3)=A3),0))=I$1),"Inactive","Active"),
if(index($E$1:$H$1,match(max($E3:$H3),$E3:$H3,0))=I$1,"Active","Inactive"))

Link to spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GHN8-uX4RdkMz0IIvTTxB0TjAKtUMSdCTFHqXNgHVm4/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=FILTER($E3:$H3,$E3:$H3-Max($E3:$H3),"")` to create an array of all loans with the highest interest rates. I suppose it ought to be possible to create a matching array of loan sizes and then extract the highest of these. However, the task appears intimidating.

Meanwhile I wonder if this much simpler approach will allow you to get to your desired result using simple IF functions.

```
=IF(A3=MAX($A3:$D3),"Hi loan","Low loan") & " / " & IF(E3=MAX($E3:$H3),"Hi Rate","Low rate")
```

You chose "Active" and "Inactive". I chose "Hi" and "Low". Both of these are translations of *True* and *False* and may be used in conditional formatting, for example, where you simply highlight loans with the highest interest rate in one colour, and choose a different colour where the highest rate is applied to the largest loan. The simple logic I express here can be expressed in words, too. It's just a matter of interpreting the two results provided by my formula to best suit your needs.